# MySQL give wrong output when same procedure is called consecutively

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures, logic

I created a procedure that fetches users profile based on user email and password

When Password is wrong STATUS = 2

When Email is wrong STATUS = 0

When Both are correct STATUS = 1

> Now the problem is when call this procedure consecutively (whole query give below in a single go), for first procedure email and password is right STATUS = 1 received but in second procedure if email is wrong it still gives STATUS = 1 but it should give 0. But if I call procedure one at a time it give right results.

```
-- Correct email and pass
CALL GetUserProfile("ankit11101998@gmail.com","abcde", @status, @PhoneNumber, @country, @photo, @emailId, @name, @msg); SELECT @status, @PhoneNumber, @country, @photo, @emailId, @name, @msg;
-- Wrong email and pass
CALL GetUserProfile("aaaaaankit11101998@gmail.com","abcde", @status, @PhoneNumber, @country, @photo, @emailId, @name, @msg); SELECT @status, @PhoneNumber, @country, @photo, @emailId, @name, @msg;
```

> Result of right email and pass

```html
+---------+--------------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+-------+---------+
| @status | @PhoneNumber | @country | @photo    | @emailId                | @name | @msg    |
+---------+--------------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+-------+---------+
|       1 | 6284567890   |       93 | imagelink | ankit11101998@gmail.com | akash | success |
+---------+--------------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+-------+---------+
```

> Result of wrong email and pass

```html
+---------+--------------+----------+--------+----------+-------+---------+
| @status | @PhoneNumber | @country | @photo | @emailId | @name | @msg    |
+---------+--------------+----------+--------+----------+-------+---------+
|       1 | NULL         |     NULL | NULL   | NULL     | NULL  | success |
+---------+--------------+----------+--------+----------+-------+---------+
```

> GetUserProfile Procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetUserProfile`(IN `UserSignUp` VARCHAR(350), IN `pWord` TEXT, OUT `status` INT, OUT `PhoneNumber` TEXT, OUT `country` INT, OUT `userphoto` TEXT, OUT `emailId` TEXT, OUT `username` TEXT, OUT `msg` TEXT)
   READS SQL DATA
   COMMENT '0 = user dont exists, 1 = success, 2 - wrong pword'
BEGIN
  SET @yesNo = 0;
  CALL UserAuth( UserSignUp, pWord,  @yesNo );
  IF @yesNo = 0 THEN                           
     SET msg = "user don't exists";
  END IF;
  IF @yesNo = 1 THEN 
     SELECT name, email, photo, mobile_no, countryCode INTO  username, emailId, userphoto, PhoneNumber, country FROM App_users
     WHERE  email = LOWER ( UserSignUp ) AND password = pWord ;
     SET msg = "success";
  END IF;
  IF @yesNo = 2 THEN
     SET msg = "wrong password";  
  END IF;
  SET status = @yesNo;
END
```

> UserAuth Procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `UserAuth`(IN `UserEmail` VARCHAR(350), IN `PWord` TEXT, OUT `success` INT)
    READS SQL DATA
    COMMENT ' status =2 :  pw error, status =0: user dont extsts'
BEGIN

SET success = 0;
SELECT password INTO @Word FROM App_users WHERE email = LOWER( UserEmail );

IF  @Word IS NOT NULL THEN
    IF @Word = PWord THEN
        SET success = 1;
    ELSE
        SET success = 2;
    END IF;
END IF;
```

END

can anyone help or suggest something to solve this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit yor question

Comment: I have changed the images to code, can you please help now.

Comment: Don 't save passwords in plain text that is a securityt hazard, hash them before saving a them and comapring

Comment: I am bcryting the password currently only for test purposes they are saved as plane

Answer (score 1):

You se3cond call doesn't overwrite the session variable @word, so you have to reset, every time you call it it

**AND don't save passwords in plain text**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE App_users
>     (`PhoneNumber` bigint, `country` int, `photo` varchar(9), `email` varchar(23),`mobile_no` int 
>     , `name` varchar(5), `password` varchar(5),`countryCode` int)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO App_users
>     (`PhoneNumber`, `country`, `photo`, `email`,`mobile_no`, `name`,`password`,`countryCode`)
> VALUES
>     (6284567890, 93, 'imagelink', 'ankit11101998@gmail.com', 11111, 'akash','abcde', 99)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE `GetUserProfile`(IN `UserSignUp` VARCHAR(350), IN `pWord` TEXT, OUT `status` INT, OUT `PhoneNumber` TEXT, OUT `country` INT, OUT `userphoto` TEXT, OUT `emailId` TEXT, OUT `username` TEXT, OUT `msg` TEXT)
>    READS SQL DATA
>    COMMENT '0 = user dont exists, 1 = success, 2 - wrong pword'
> BEGIN
>   SET @yesNo = 0;
>   CALL UserAuth( UserSignUp, pWord,  @yesNo );
>   IF @yesNo = 0 THEN                           
>      SET msg = "user don't exists";
>   END IF;
>   IF @yesNo = 1 THEN 
>      SELECT name, email, photo, mobile_no, countryCode INTO  username, emailId, userphoto, PhoneNumber, country FROM App_users
>      WHERE  email = LOWER ( UserSignUp ) AND password = pWord ;
>      SET msg = "success";
>   END IF;
>   IF @yesNo = 2 THEN
>      SET msg = "wrong password";  
>   END IF;
>   SET status = @yeso;
> END
> ```

> ```
> CREATE  PROCEDURE `UserAuth`(IN `UserEmail` VARCHAR(350), IN `PWord` TEXT, OUT `success` INT)
>     READS SQL DATA
>     COMMENT ' status =2 :  pw error, status =0: user dont extsts'
> BEGIN
> SET @Word = '';
> SET success = 0;
> SELECT password INTO @Word FROM App_users WHERE email = LOWER( UserEmail );
>
> IF  @Word IS NOT NULL THEN
>     IF @Word = PWord THEN
>         SET success = 1;
>     ELSE
>         SET success = 2;
>     END IF;
> END IF;
> END
> ```

> ```
> -- Correct email and pass
> CALL GetUserProfile("ankit11101998@gmail.com","abcde", @status, @PhoneNumber, @country, @photo, @emailId, @name, @msg); 
> SELECT @status, @PhoneNumber, @country, @photo, @emailId, @name, @msg;
> -- Wrong email and pass
> ```

> ```
> ✓
>
> @status | @PhoneNumber | @country | @photo    | @emailId                | @name | @msg   
> ------: | :----------- | -------: | :-------- | :---------------------- | :---- | :------
>    null | 11111        |       99 | imagelink | ankit11101998@gmail.com | akash | success
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CALL GetUserProfile("aaaaaankit11101998@gmail.com","abcde", @status, @PhoneNumber, @country, @photo, @emailId, @name, @msg); 
> SELECT @status, @PhoneNumber, @country, @photo, @emailId, @name, @msg;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> @status | @PhoneNumber | @country | @photo | @emailId | @name | @msg          
> ------: | :----------- | -------: | :----- | :------- | :---- | :-------------
>    null | null         |     null | null   | null     | null  | wrong password
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=860057cc042ba34a5bbf4def2f2f1aab)*